# How login FTP server using ssh private key and credential

Tags: vbscript, ftp, ssh-keys

Hope everyone is doing well, 
I have one new request from the client.

We sends files from our server to one FTP server.
But now client want to use new credential and private ssh key for that FTP server and he shared the same with us.

We have opened the new port also, but I am unable to login into FTP server. Did I need to do something to login or is their different ways to login for the same.

Regards,
Mustafa

Comment: You probably mistake FTP with SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

FTP can use SSL, which supports client authentication using X.509 certificates. However, while many FTP servers support FTPS, I don't know of any which support client certificates. (In addition, client authentication is complicated in SSL – in many cases, you would have to create and maintain your own certificate authority and stuff. Not many clients support this kind of authentication, either.)

Much easier is to use SFTP, the SSH file transfer protocol. It uses exactly the same keys as "normal" SSH would. On Windows, WinSCP and FileZilla support SFTP.

Comment: The OP is using *private SSH key.* -- So clearly the OP is using SSH/SFTP, not FTP. - - On the other hand, most FTPS servers ***DO** support client certificates*. But I believe it's irrelevant to this question anyway.